# Pushing to mongoose array by ID not getting ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to add a subscribed classes object to my mongodb, however, when I push the new subscribed classes to the database it doesn't work due to it not getting the user _id.

So far I have tried this code along with some other things like findone

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    password: String,
    secret: String,
    classes: [String]
});

const userModel = mongoose.model("Class", userSchema)

const newClass = req.body.subClass;
const id = req.user.id
    userModel.findById(id, function (err, user) {
        if (user) {
            console.log(user)
            db.users.update(
                { _id: id },
                { $push: { classes: newClass } }
            )
        } else {
            console.log(err)
        }
    })
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I can advise

1. Change update to findOneAndUpdate the purpose of both processing an update statment on a "singular" document, as well as retrieving the content of that "singular" document.
2. Before passing id convert it to ObjectId
3. Change (db.users.update) db to userModel

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
userModel.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: new ObjectId(id) },
  { $push: { classes: newClass  } },
  { upsert: false, new: true }, // upsert looks to find a Message with that id and if it doesn't exist creates the Message if argument is true 
);
```

Hope will help you

Run this file node index.js and change your codes with this help!

```
// index.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
const mongoDB = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1/test';
mongoose.connect(mongoDB, { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true,useFindAndModify: false });

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    password: String,
    secret: String,
    classes: [String]
});

(async function  createAndUpdate(){
    // create user
    const userModel = mongoose.model("Class", userSchema);
    const newUser = new userModel({
        email: 'user@gmail.com',
        password: 'password',
        secret: 'secret',
        classes: 'classes1'
    });
    await newUser.save();

    // update user
    const newClass = 'new-classes2';
    const id = newUser._id;
    await userModel.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: new ObjectId(id) },
        { $push: { classes: newClass  } },
        { upsert: false }
    );
})();
```

Comment: The code runs smoothly, however it doesn't add the newclass into the array, and instead just gives back a document ID when i look at it in studio 3t

Comment: Edited for clarity.

Comment: The problem with this code is that I am already using passport for new user creation....

```User.register({ username: req.body.username }, req.body.password, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            red.redirect("/register")
        } else {
            passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function () {
                res.redirect("/dashboard")
            })
        }
    })
});``` 

which looks like that, is there any way to do this without using the async function for creating users?